# correlation of frequency of binary data and discrete data

Tags: r, correlation, autoregressive

I have two columns that one shows size and another shows a specific binary behavior (0/1), like the following.

```
size, behavior
2, 0
2, 1
3, 1
5, 1
5, 1
.
.
.
```

I want to know if the discrete column (size) positively impact the probability of the behavior. How can I do it properly in R or Python?

Comment: There are many threads related to the correlation between numeric and binary variables on this site. As for R or Python coding guidelines, I'm afraid this is off-topic per [our FAQ](https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: It sounds like you want to conduct a [logistic regression](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/logistic%2bregression?tab=Votes).